# How are a Debian package's dependencies handled when it requires "package A or package B" for dependencies?

Tags: apt, dependencies

In Ubuntu 12.04 (and Debian and the other Ubuntu versions), the `nginx` meta-package has dependencies listed on `nginx-full` or `nginx-light`.  What is the rule of which of those dependencies the system will try and install first?  Or is it just random?

Answer (score 0):

The meta-package provided as part of the `nginx` source package depend on either `nginx-light` or `nginx-full`.  What that means is when you install `nginx` the first of the dependencies listed will be tried, and if that is not available, it will try the other dependency.

In a rare case that a package's dependencies are missing, the package will fail, and `apt` will report that there's dependency issues.

With the `nginx` source package, though, the binaries for `nginx-light` and `nginx-full` are both part of the same source package, so doing `sudo apt-get install nginx` will fail unless you enable the universe repositories.  By enabling the universe repositories, `nginx-light` and `nginx-full` and the other variants of the nginx binaries (each having their own set of "loaded" nginx modules) will all be available, so you wouldn't run into this dependency issue, except when using `nginx-extras` or `nginx-naxsi` in place of `nginx-light` or `nginx-full`.

Comment: I have seen this first-hand myself on my systems, which is why I avoid using the metapackage, and instead just rely on installing the binary package I want, rather than relying on the metapackage.  (Also note I have answered with the `nginx`-package-specific stuff because I'm kinda fluent with how that package is laid out.  And because I've seen this first-hand in the requirements for the `nginx` meta package)